# Using gather on an already gathered-like data.frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data.frame in R that contains ages, lengths, and the total count of individuals within each length group. I want to get mean and standard deviation of lengths for each age group, and I feel doing this with dplyr will be easiest. However, I can't seem to figure out how to `gather()` this particular dataset. Here is the data:

```
dat <- data.frame(age = sort(rep(1:5, 5)),
              length = c(6:10, 8:12, 10:14, 12:16, 14:18),
              total = sample(25:50, 50, replace=T))
```

which looks like this:

```
  age length total
   1      6    38
   1      7    42
   1      8    49
   1      9    28
   1     10    26
   2      8    37
```

And, I want it to look like the following so that I can easily `group_by(age) %>% summarize(mean = mean(length), sd = sd(length))`.

```
age  length
1     6
1     6
1     6
1     6
1     6
```

etc. (i.e. there should be 38 6s for age 1, 42 7s for age 1 and so on).

How can I achieve this using the `gather()` function from tidyr? I can't seem to be able to do it. Happy to hear alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

How about calculating the weighted mean instead?

```
dat <- data.frame(age = sort(rep(1:5, 5)),
                  length = c(6:10, 8:12, 10:14, 12:16, 14:18),
                  total = sample(25:50, 50, replace=T))
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(age) %>%
  summarise(mean_length = sum(length * total) / sum(total),
            wtd_mean = weighted.mean(length, total))
```

EDIT: it occurred to me after posting earlier that R has a `weighted.mean` function that makes this even simpler.

Comment: I had done something like this, but it gets a bit hairier when calculating standard deviation. :|

Comment: See `?Hmisc::wtd.var`.  `Hmisc` also has a `wtd.quantile` if you're into non-parametric measures.